# Why does karma preprocessor not properly parse CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, karma-runner

I have:

```
$http
  url: '/api/v1/session/check'
  method: 'POST'
  data: sessionCheck
.success (response) =>
  if response.authenticated is true
    @user = response.user

  deferred.resolve response
.error (data, status, headers, config) ->
  deferred.reject data
  throw {
    data: data
    status: status
    headers: headers
    config: config
  }
```

And in my `karma.conf.coffee`, I have:

```
preprocessors:
  'public/scripts/**/*.coffee': ['coverage']
  'test/webapp/unit/**/*.coffee': ['coffee']

singleRun: true


reporters: ['story', 'coverage']

coverageReporter:
  type: 'html'
  dir: 'test/webapp/coverage/'
```

But when I run my test, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR [preprocessor.coverage]: Syntax error on line 59, column 8: unexpected '.' (\u002E)
56 :           url: '/api/v1/session/check'
57 :           method: 'POST'
58 :           data: sessionCheck
59 :         .success (response) =>
^^ :~~~~~~~~^
60 :           if response.authenticated is true
61 :             @user = response.user
62 :
```

Which, of course, makes no sense to me. Because if I change the code to:

```
$http(
  url: '/api/v1/session/check'
  method: 'POST'
  data: sessionCheck
).success((response) =>
  if response.authenticated is true
    @user = response.user

  deferred.resolve response
).error((data, status, headers, config) ->
  deferred.reject data
  throw {
    data: data
    status: status
    headers: headers
    config: config
  }
)
```

then it works fine. Those 2 snippets of CoffeeScript compile to **identical** JavaScript, so what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest karma-coffee-preprocessor?
Looks like your karma preprocessor uses outdated version of coffeescript (<1.7).
Method chaining without parenthesis was added only in 1.7, which came out not so long ago.